# dot2texi: Use latex labels (texlbl) with clusters

Tags: math-mode, dot2tex, dot2texi

I'm using the `dot2texi` package to include dot graphs in my tex files. With nodes, I can use `texlbl="$n_1$"` to create a label  n<sub>1</sub>. I want to have tex labels also on clusters:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{dot2tex}[dot,tikz,options=-s]
    digraph G {
      n1 [texlbl="$n_1$"];
      subgraph cluster_1 {
        texlbl = "$c_1$";
        n2 [texlbl = "$n_2$"];
      }
    }
  \end{dot2tex}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, no cluster label is shown:

[image: cluster label set with texlbl]

If I replace `texlbl = "$c_1$"` with `label = "$c_1$"` then the label is `$c_1$` instead of c<sub>1</sub>:

[image: cluster set with label]

Is there any way to have a `texlbl` as cluster label? Or how else can I use math environments in cluster labels?